# Upgrading Artifactory 6.23.42 to 7.41.14 failing derby db migration v60

Tags: upgrade, artifactory, derby

Attempting to upgrade from Artifactory 6.23.42 to 7.41.14 (both Pro). The 7.41.14 is the last version that supports jdk 11 and there is [unspecific](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-installation-setup-documentation/system-requirements) warning about JDK 17 support on CentOS 7.

> Note that JDK 17 and Tomcat 9.x are not supported on all Centos 7.x versions.

My environment:

- CentOS 7.9.2009
- Derby db
- RPM installs

  - `jfrog-artifactory-pro-6.23.42.rpm`
  - `jfrog-artifactory-pro-7.41.14.rpm`

What I did:

- systemctl stop artifactory
- yum update jfrog-artifactory-pro-7.41.14.rpm
- systemctl start artifactory

Results:

- No errors in `migration.log`

The db migration completes a bunch of steps but dies with:
`Failed to execute query: 'ALTER TABLE' cannot be performed on 'REPLICATION_ERRORS' because it does not exist.`

The `artifactory-service.log` shows a failed db migration:

```
2023-04-06T17:18:15.512Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [af075423d2f70fd8] [o.j.c.AbstractDbConverter:51  ] [Catalina-utility-2  ] - Converter `v59` is done with status `SKIPPED`.
2023-04-06T17:18:15.531Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [af075423d2f70fd8] [o.j.c.AbstractDbConverter:36  ] [Catalina-utility-2  ] - Starting converter v60 with description: "Add column `event_category` to table `replication_errors`."
2023-04-06T17:18:15.532Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [af075423d2f70fd8] [j.c.u.PreDefinedConverters:398] [Catalina-utility-2  ] - Searching for default DB conversion template at /templates/default/add_column.tpl
2023-04-06T17:18:15.534Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [af075423d2f70fd8] [j.c.u.PreDefinedConverters:404] [Catalina-utility-2  ] - Searching for concrete DB (derby) conversion template at /templates/derby/add_column.tpl
2023-04-06T17:18:15.539Z [jfrt ] [WARN ] [af075423d2f70fd8] [o.j.s.u.DbStatementUtils:62   ] [Catalina-utility-2  ] - Failed to execute query: 'ALTER TABLE' cannot be performed on 'REPLICATION_ERRORS' because it does not exist.:
ALTER TABLE replication_errors ADD COLUMN event_category VARCHAR(225)
2023-04-06T17:18:15.540Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [af075423d2f70fd8] [o.j.c.AbstractDbConverter:51  ] [Catalina-utility-2  ] - Converter `v60` is done with status `FAILED`.
2023-04-06T17:18:15.552Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [af075423d2f70fd8] [d.c.m.ConverterManagerImpl:278] [Catalina-utility-2  ] - Conversion failed. You should analyze the error and retry launching Artifactory. Error is: Failed to convert v60 : Failed to convert v60
2023-04-06T17:18:15.557Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [af075423d2f70fd8] [tifactoryHomeConfigListener:55] [Catalina-utility-2  ] - Failed initializing Home. Caught exception:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to convert v60 : Failed to convert v60
       at org.artifactory.storage.db.converter.markers.ConverterManagerImpl.handleException(ConverterManagerImpl.java:281)
       at org.artifactory.storage.db.converter.markers.ConverterManagerImpl.serviceConvert(ConverterManagerImpl.java:238)
       at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655)
       at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)
       at org.artifactory.storage.db.converter.markers.ConverterManagerImpl.convertDatabase(ConverterManagerImpl.java:156)
       at org.artifactory.lifecycle.storage.db.init.PostDbSchemaInitializationManager.convertAndInit(PostDbSchemaInitializationManager.java:61)
       at org.artifactory.lifecycle.storage.db.init.HaInitLock.runInsideInitLockIfNeeded(HaInitLock.java:110)
       at org.artifactory.lifecycle.storage.db.init.PostDbSchemaInitializationManager.init(PostDbSchemaInitializationManager.java:50)
       at org.artifactory.lifecycle.webapp.servlet.BasicConfigurationManager.initArtifactoryInstallation(BasicConfigurationManager.java:154)
       at org.artifactory.lifecycle.webapp.servlet.BasicConfigurationManager.initialize(BasicConfigurationManager.java:126)
       at org.artifactory.lifecycle.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryHomeConfigListener.initBasicConfigManager(ArtifactoryHomeConfigListener.java:61)
       at org.artifactory.lifecycle.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryHomeConfigListener.contextInitialized(ArtifactoryHomeConfigListener.java:53)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4768)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5230)
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:698)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:696)
       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:690)
       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1889)
       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
       at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.jfrog.converter.DbConverterRuntimeException: Failed to convert v60
       at org.artifactory.storage.db.DatabaseConverterAdapter.convert(DatabaseConverterAdapter.java:49)
       at org.artifactory.storage.db.converter.markers.ConverterManagerImpl.serviceConvert(ConverterManagerImpl.java:234)
       ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.jfrog.converter.DbConverterExecutionException: Failed to convert v60
       at org.jfrog.converter.util.DbConverterUtil.executeConverters(DbConverterUtil.java:79)
       at org.jfrog.converter.util.DbConverterUtil.calculateAndExecute(DbConverterUtil.java:114)
       at org.artifactory.storage.db.DatabaseConverterAdapter.convert(DatabaseConverterAdapter.java:44)
       ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.jfrog.converter.DbConverterExecutionException: Failed to convert v60
       at org.jfrog.converter.predefined.PreDefinedDbConverter.executeConverter(PreDefinedDbConverter.java:37)
       at org.jfrog.converter.AbstractDbConverter.convert(AbstractDbConverter.java:39)
       at org.jfrog.converter.util.DbConverterUtil.executeConverters(DbConverterUtil.java:75)
       ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: 'ALTER TABLE' cannot be performed on 'REPLICATION_ERRORS' because it does not exist.
       at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
       at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
       at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source)
       at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
       at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source)
       at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown Source)
       at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
       at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(Unknown Source)
       at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
       at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyStatement.java:120)
       at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyStatement.java)
       at org.jfrog.storage.dbtype.DefaultDbTypeHelper.executeUpdateQuery(DefaultDbTypeHelper.java:68)
       at org.jfrog.storage.util.DbStatementUtils.executeSqlStream(DbStatementUtils.java:57)
       at org.jfrog.converter.predefined.PreDefinedDbConverter.executeConverter(PreDefinedDbConverter.java:35)
       ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException: 'ALTER TABLE' cannot be performed on 'REPLICATION_ERRORS' because it does not exist.
       at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
       at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
       at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.DDLStatementNode.justGetDescriptor(Unknown Source)
       at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.DDLStatementNode.getTableDescriptor(Unknown Source)
       at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.DDLStatementNode.getTableDescriptor(Unknown Source)
       at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.AlterTableNode.bindStatement(Unknown Source)
       at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepMinion(Unknown Source)
       at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
       at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.conn.GenericLanguageConnectionContext.prepareInternalStatement(Unknown Source)
       ... 38 common frames omitted
2023-04-06T17:18:15.577Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [af075423d2f70fd8] [actoryContextConfigListener:90] [Catalina-utility-2  ] - Failed initializing Artifactory context: Artifactory home not initialized.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it seems during the upgrade process,Artifactory had an issue creating the 'REPLICATION_ERRORS' table, if this behavior persists after trying to restart the service, it is possible to create this table manually, and it should help resolve this error.

**As it require to perform manual changes to the DB, it is recommended to backup the DB before making the changes.**

You may use the following workaround the create the missing table and its corresponding indexes:

1. Stop Artifacory
2. Connect to your Derby DB by following these [instructions](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-connect-to-a-derby-db-and-run-different-queries/) (for Artifactory 7.x)
3. Run the following SQL queries in the Derby database:

```
CREATE TABLE replication_errors
(
    error_id         BIGINT        NOT NULL,
    first_error_time BIGINT        NOT NULL,
    last_error_time  BIGINT        NOT NULL,
    error_count      SMALLINT      NOT NULL,
    error_message    VARCHAR(4000) NOT NULL,
    replication_key  VARCHAR(255)  NOT NULL,
    task_time        BIGINT        NOT NULL,
    task_type        SMALLINT      NOT NULL,
    task_path        VARCHAR(1344) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT replication_errors_pk PRIMARY KEY (error_id)
);
```

4. After creating the table, run this command to create its corresponding index:

`CREATE INDEX replication_errors_rep_key_idx ON replication_errors (replication_key);`

5. Update the "schema_change_log" table so it can rerun the skipped conversions:

`UPDATE schema_change_log SET status='FAILED' WHERE version='v60';`

6. Once done with the changes, disconnect from the Derby DB and start Artifactory.

Comment: First, thanks for the detailed instructions. The steps completed as described. Now it complains `Failed to convert v61` ... `OPERATION_KEY was not found on table: REPLICATION_ERRORS`. I can go poking around on my other instance to see what fields are missing on REPLICATION_ERRORS. Is there anyway to see the list of all migrations pending?

Comment: Is it safer to first attempt the [least change supported](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-installation-setup-documentation/upgrading-from-artifactory-version-6.10.x-onwards-to-7.x) update to 7.21.3? Might that handle the delta of db migrations better as it's the prescribed update from 6.23.21+? I'm assuming the migrations in 7.41.14 are expecting a db state that my 6.23 does not have.

Comment: The migrations should take place either way, in case you already started the upgrade process and doesn't have a backup of the old version to roll back to and start the upgrade again it wan't be recommended to try and downgrade while already in the process.

Comment: As mentioned before, it is highly recommended to **backup the DB** before making any changes, in case it will be required to rollback to the previous state.

Regarding the `v6` and `OPERATION_KEY` errors, possible to try following the steps below:
Stop Artifactory and connect to the Derby DB
If the columns names mentioned on the left side below already exists in the `replication_errors` table, it may be required to rename them:

“replication_key" to "operation_key”, "task_time" to "event_time", "task_type" to "event_type", "task_path" to "path"

Comment: `RENAME COLUMN <table_name.old_column_name> to <new_column_name>;`  
E.g: `RENAME COLUMN replication_errors.replication_key to operation_key;`

Drop the `replication_errors_rep_key_idx` and recreate it:
`DROP INDEX replication_errors_rep_key_idx;`
`CREATE INDEX replication_errors_rep_key_idx ON replication_errors (operation_key);`

Update the `schema_change_log` table:
`UPDATE schema_change_log SET status='FAILED' WHERE version='v61';`

disconnect from the Derby DB and start Artifactory.

Comment: Renaming the columns allowed migration v61 to complete. The rest of the migrations completed without error and the artifactory-service process started up along with the other microservices.
The only remaining question is are there db migrations for `replication_errors` table that should have been run that would have addressed these two error states? Is there a regression in updating from 6.23.42 to 7.x that could be avoided by either doing a smaller jump (7.21.3) or a complete update to 7.55.10?
Thanks again for your help.

Comment: The version that was upgraded, to and from (in this case 6.23.42 to 7.41.14) should be supported and in a similar way also an upgrade to a higher version, the behavior encountered in this case might be related to the Derby DB, in general it is highly recommended to use an external DB rather the Derby that comes out of the box, like MySQL, PSQL etc... especially if the environment considered for Production.

Comment: Just wanted to come back and close the loop. Migrating the db from derby to an external Postgresql first did then allow the upgrade and migration to complete smoothly.

Comment: Very helpful for my 4.14.1->6.23.42->7.63.7. I'd similar derby errors. The derby SQL seemed to work to get 7.63.7 migrated and running but my users/groups were lost and artifacts didn't seem to be completely there. Exporting 6.23.42 system and importing with a pgsql setup then performing the steps for 6.23.42->7.63.7 went a lot smoother. Setting up an nginx proxy from start also helped. I'd been trying to have tomcat listen on 80 and force redirect to 443 this seems no longer to be an option, maybe to avoid running jfrog as root. I also did sha2 & pathChecksum migrations in 6.23.42. Thanks!